# Whenever I boot I get Visual Artifacts, why? Is there a way to fix it?

Tags: boot, screen, visual-artifacts

I have a desktop with a old Nvidia 6150SE Nforce 430 and I can't boot up every time I try the system shows the desktop wallpaper and a cursor and then freezes and shows me a colorful pattern across the screen and I have to reboot and it does it every time I Boot into Ubuntu I'm running 12.04.3 the same thing happens with Linux Mint 15 Mate. I need this working I cant even access the grub bootloader to change options

Comment: He mentioned a "colorful pattern." Can you describe it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj is not a dupe, see answer above. **Close Voters** no answer there will solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible causes of your problem:

1. Your Nvidia GeForce 6150 SE nForce 430 graphics card is going bad. This would explain why everything related to graphics is causing your system to freeze. A bad graphics card is a common cause of this problem.
2. You don't have the minimum system requirements necessary for installing Ubuntu 12.04. This is less likely in my opinion, because Ubuntu 12.04 only requires 384MB RAM. However the Nvidia GeForce 6150 SE nForce 430 graphics card shares up to 256MB of your system RAM, so that would increase your minimum system requirement for RAM up to 640MB. If that is your problem, then you would need to install a more lightweight *buntu version such as Lubuntu 13.10, which somewhat resembles Windows XP in look and feel.

Comment: If the same happens with Mint, I am 200% sure that is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this can also be a memory problem. Do a test to the memory with grub. I had some problems like this one on older computers. In some cases it was also the motherboard.